# whitespace text nodes in the Chrome DOM

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox, dom

The below HTML:

```html
    <html>
      <body>
          <label>field a</label>
          <input  name="foo1" value=""/><br/>
          <label>field b</label><input name="foo2" value="" /><br/>
      </body>
    </html>
```

… renders the input of field a slightly off to the right due to the whitespace between the `label` and the first `input` element. However, looking at the DOM in Chrome I see this:

[image]

I.e. there is no representation of the text node in the DOM. Since the browser renders it with the extra space I think what's happenning is that a whitespace is indeed present in the DOM but the DOM viewer for some reason does not display it. If I understand correctly Firefox DevTools do in fact display whitespace text nodes (see this [blog post](https://blog.nightly.mozilla.org/2016/10/17/devtools-now-display-white-space-text-nodes-in-the-dom-inspector/)). Is there anything similar for Chrome?

Comment: Firefox *does* show them. I've been enjoying this lovely feature for a long time.

Comment: yes, just confirmed that Firefox 73.0.1 (64bit) has them

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a way to display them in the DOM view.

However, I've noticed they are somewhat detectable in the *Accessibility Tree*:

[image]